# How to make OS X Server 3 accessible from the internet?

Tags: macos, network, server.app, dns

I am trying to setup an OS X server so that I can see it from outside of my internal network.

I have OS X Mavericks with the Server app installed as a VM for testing purposes right now. It has access to the internet and I can browse it from my local Macs on the network.

I would like to be able to set it up as a basic web server to which I can set up a website or a small cloud backup etc.

I have various domain names which I use for my website and I could repurpose one of these or purchase a new one if needed.

I tried just turning on the Websites option which didn't work, I did have a play around with the DNS options adding in the IP of my domain etc but didn't get anywhere.

Do I need anything else besides a Mac with OS X Server and a domain name? Or am I missing something completely?

I am fairly technical but this is a bit out of my depths here I have done my google searching but everything I seem to find is always based to set up a local web host or within a corporate network.

If anyone can point me in the right directions I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please add some facts about your network setup. Which kind of connection do you have (e.g DSL, Cable etc) and do use a router? Do you have a permanent or changing IP.

Comment: OSX Mavericks running as a VM with access to the internet, Dynamic IP from BT, Apple Airport express dishing out the IPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you have to make your server accessible behind a router  with a frequently changing IP-adress with a fixed fqdn for the router and forward all http/https requests from the WAN to the OS X VM in the LAN.

1. Set up [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS):

   - Get an arbitrary name from a dynamic DNS service provider (like [Dyn](http://dyn.com/dns/) (not free) or [NO-IP](http://www.noip.com/) (free))
   - or depending on your hosting service and the access level you have, set up your own [DDNS service](http://andrwe.org/linux/own-ddns)
2. Set up a [DDNS client](http://fwroller.com/xproddns/) on your OS X Server
3. Set up your OS X Server VM with a fixed IP
4. Set up and check port-forwarding (default is 80/443) on your Airport Express (some firmware versions seem to be buggy) to the OS X Server VM.
5. Access your home web server  from the internet with the chosen fqdn (e.g. (www.)myserver.no-ip.com).
6. Consider setting up some countermeasures against evil attackers.

Comment: Thank you @klanomath, that all seems to be working, simple easy instructions, had a bit of an issue with the port forwarding but got it accessible from the outside world.